# Arguments for/ against duplicate Keys in Properties file

Tags: properties, configuration-files

I work in a QA department and, as part of my job, often times look at the configuration files prepared by our developers. On occasion, i see that particular keys are redefined as configuration file goes on

```
A = 12
...
A = 34
```

To me this looks like a very bad practice. At the end of the day, it is not clear what `A` is equal to and since program logic is hidden, it is not clear whether application is handling this case properly, or, perhaps there is a very good reason why things are done this way.

Additionally, from time to time, i see

```
A = 12
...
A = puppies
```

The meaning assigned to the key seems to be very ambiguous. Is developer building variations of what `A` may be equal to? Is first `A` a typo? Many questions remain ..

I wonder ... **Is there ever a good reason why developers would configure their apps to redefine Keys (include duplicate keys)**, or .. am i correct to question this?

NB: The application works fine with the duplicate keys, however it is handled, it appears to  work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After speaking with several developers with decades of experience, the answer to my question is a resounding "NO". There is no good reason for a configuration file to contain duplicate keys.